# Merging data with data.table roll="nearest" rolls matches across the entire DF

Tags: r, data.table

I have two tables, a sample table and a message table. In the message table, messages are recorded outside the sampling rate of the tracker. What I have been doing is using data.table roll nearest to match the sample message time to the closest value in the sample report. Instead of returning the sample message to the nearest time and NAs for everything else, it seems that it is rolling messages until the next message.

```
library(data.table)
remotes::install.github("dmirman/gazer") # to get the data
library((gazer)
```

```
samp <- system.file("extdata", "TJ_samp.xls", package = "gazer")
samp <- data.table::fread(samp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # reads in large datasets 

msg <- system.file("extdata", "TJ_msg.xls", package = "gazer")
msg <- data.table::fread(msg, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # reads in large datasets
```

```
setDT(samp)
setDT(msg)

DT_mesg <- msg[samp, on="time", roll="nearest"] # use this to get close to values in sample report

DT_mesg
```

```
 #SR edfs are a nightmare. This makes it so messages are alined with closest values 
get_msg <- DT_mesg %>% 
  group_by(trial, message) %>% 
  top_n(n=1, wt=desc(time)) # there are a lot of useless messages and they occupy the same time stamp. Only take the first message in time. This was one way I tried to deal with the multiple message issue, but it does not return messages close to their actual time. 

get_msg
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out...

```
setDT(samp)
setDT(msg)

DT_mesg <- msg[samp, on="time", roll=4]
```

This gives me my desired result:

```
  trial    time                     message i.trial     x     y  pup Label
     1:     1 3314705 !MODE RECORD CR 250 2 1 L\n       1 958.8 580.8 4043  <NA>
     2:    NA 3314709                        <NA>       1 959.1 576.2 4052  <NA>
     3:    NA 3314713                        <NA>       1 959.8 575.6 4053  <NA>
     4:    NA 3314717                        <NA>       1 960.6 575.2 4056  <NA>
     5:    NA 3314721                        <NA>       1 960.2 579.6 4049  <NA>
```

Not sure why roll="nearest" returns this:

```
   trial    time                     message i.trial     x     y  pup Label
     1:     1 3314705 !MODE RECORD CR 250 2 1 L\n       1 958.8 580.8 4043  <NA>
     2:     1 3314709 !MODE RECORD CR 250 2 1 L\n       1 959.1 576.2 4052  <NA>
     3:     1 3314713 !MODE RECORD CR 250 2 1 L\n       1 959.8 575.6 4053  <NA>
     4:     1 3314717 !MODE RECORD CR 250 2 1 L\n       1 960.6 575.2 4056  <NA>
     5:     1 3314721 !MODE RECORD CR 250 2 1 L\n       1 960.2 579.6 4049  <NA>
```